# Limit number of values inputted depending on the value from a certain field

Tags: angular, maxlength

I have **3** fields, n, x, and y.

**n** will set the maximum number of values that can be input in x and y fields.

I tried using `maxlength = {{n}}` in x and y fields, it works but I want to exclude spaces and special characters and include only integers in counting the length.

```
<label class="item item-input">
     <span class="input-label">
         <b><font color="red"><b>*</b></font>x :</b>
     </span>
     <input type="tel" name="n" inputmode="numeric" required=""></input>
</label>
<label class="item item-input">
     <span class="input-label">
         <b><font color="red"><b>*</b></font>x :</b>
     </span>
     <input type="tel" name="x" ng-model="x" inputmode="numeric" required=""></input>
</label>
<label class="item item-input">
     <span class="input-label">
         <b><font color="red"><b>*</b></font>x :</b>
     </span>
     <input type="tel" name="y" ng-model="y" inputmode="numeric" required=""></input>
</label>
```

Comment: This question would really benefit from showing some code. At the moment, it is unclear if the 3 fields are html fields, or just typescript variables.

Comment: Sounds like you need a regex pattern as well... just use `pattern` for that.

Comment: @Zze i added some code